# How to stop invoking @HostListner on angular onload

Tags: javascript, html, angular, jsp, event-handling

I am currently working on a change, where we use angular and jsp as front end. we are passing  element from jsp and with in this jsp we have  which is a third party URI. we are trying that whenever the page is loading the default preferences to be loaded and when we click on tab button we should apply another changes.

but due to limited knowledge on HostListener I am not able to solve.

in Angular:

```
@HostListner(window:documentTabSwitch)
documentTabSwitch(){
this.applyUserPreference();
}
```

here this documentTabSwitch() was triggered on load of page, i should prevent it from loading. only it should be invoke when Tab click.

Comment: documentTabSwitch Is not an official event I think, so there probably is a function somewhere in your app that triggers that as a custom event.

Comment: Yes, its not an official event, we actually adding this event from jsp page using javascript.